# change persistent disk type to ssd

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, snapshot, persistent-storage

I have an elasticsearch running as a ECK on a GKE cluster for production purposes and in order to increase its performance I'm thinking of changing the persistent disk type to ssd. I came accross solutions that incite the need to create a snapshot of the disk in GCE and then create another ssd disk with the data stored in the snapshot. I'm still concerned whether it still has a risk of data loss and if I create another disk will my elastic be able to match it or not as it is  statefulset.

Comment: Please provide more details on your deployment. Are you using non-standard storageClass? Is elasticsearch utilising persistent volume claim?

Comment: yes elastic is using pvc and the storage type is standard

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a production deployment I would advise to do as follows:

1. Create a volume snapshot ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots)).
2. Set up a secondary cluster ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-zonal-cluster)).
3. Modify the deployment so that it uses an SSD ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/ssd-pd)).
4. Deploy to the second cluster.

Once this new deployment has been fully tested you can switch over the traffic.